# 英語が残っている:「レビュー|クローズ票」This question has been flagged for:

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語, クローズ理由

「レビュー|クローズ票」にまだ英語が残っていました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 理由自体は翻訳されていないため、レビューでも英語になっています。これを直す必要はありますね・・・

Answer (score 0, accepted):

適当翻訳：

This question has been flagged for:

この理由でこの質問が通報された：

Comment: 翻訳案です
「この質問は次の理由で通報されました：」